# Composer in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

How to upgrade new version of module code by using composer in Magento 2 from the third-party repository.

How to upgrade third-party module using composer?
If anyone knows then please help me out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you installed the module via composer, should be referenced in composer.json in the node “require”.

For example:

```
...
“require”: {
“paypal/braintree” : “1.0.0”
}
...
```

If you want other version you should change the version to new version for example 1.2.1.

After edit composer.json

```
composer update
```

If you know the new version of the module you can update directly with:

```
composer require paypal/braintree:1.2.1
```

You can use ^ or ~ for version. More info in composer: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md